# Unison -repeat watch will only sync when a change is made client side

Tags: linux, macos, sync, unison

I have 3 computers, two clients (A,B), and one central server (C), that they both connect to via Unison/ssh, folders are set to -repeat watch so that changes are sent to the server as soon as they are made, (think dropbox).

This system works perfectly, changes are made on the server as soon as something changes in my watch folders on either client. But, changes made on (A) are not pushed to (B), through (C) until (B) makes a change itself, and visa-versa.

Is there some way to get Unison to check for changes on (C), and not just the clients?

Thanks for any help, Please let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this just turned out to be a dumb mistake on my part. The Unison versions did not match between the server and the clients. Simply updating the server's Unison version corrected the issue.

A private dropbox alternative is as simple as compiling the same latest svn version on each computer you'd like to sync, then running unison with -repeat watch!

Comment: Unison "-repeat watch" support for OSX is now possible too: https://github.com/jumpstarter-io/unox